# What is the average value of x?

Tags: random, average

I came up with this math script

x=0;
x+=Ran#ⁿ, n=0…1000000000

Ran# is a random number generator that returns a uniform random real number from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive)

ⁿ is to take the random number to the power of n.

n=0…1000000000 means n is changing from 0 to 1000000000. It's equivalent to for(int n=0; n<=1000000000; n++) .

What is the average value of x?

Comment: So you mean that the final answer is $(x_0)^0 + (x_1)^1 + (x_2)^2 + \dots + (x_{10^9})^{10^9}$, where each $x_i$ is an independent uniformly random real number from $[0,1]$?

Comment: xᵢ in your equation would be a random number (0 is inclusive, 1 is exclusive) to the power of ᵢ

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I'm understanding you correctly, this should be $$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{1000000000}x^n\,d x&=&\sum_{n=0}^{1000000000}\int_0^1x^n\,dx\\&=&\sum_{n=0}^{1000000000}\left(\left.\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right\rvert_0^1\right)\\&=&\sum_{n=0}^{1000000000}\frac{1}{n+1}\\&=&\sum_{n=1}^{1000000001}\frac{1}{n}\end{eqnarray*}$$
which is $H_{1000000001}$, the $1000000001^\text{th}$ Harmonic number.

You can approximate that with $H_n \approx \ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}$, where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.
In this case, that comes out to be about $21.3004815033$.